# Draw on Canvas From multiple threads Android 17

Tags: android, multithreading, android-canvas, draw

In an overview of the app, i get the feed from the camera on a SurfaceView and I want to draw on top of that based on the gps location (sound familiar i guess).
So in order to update the canvas without blocking the live feed I would need a new thread?
Code:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas1) {
    Log.w("MyActivity","DRAW");
    canvas = canvas1;
    super.draw(canvas);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2,30,p);
    String output = "";
    output = "Current longitude:" + Double.toString(gpsGo.RequestLocationUpdate().getLongitude()) + " latitude: " + Double.toString(gpsGo.RequestLocationUpdate().getLatitude());
    canvas.drawText(output,canvas.getWidth()/(5 - rand.nextInt(5)) + min,canvas.getHeight() - canvas.getHeight()/(5 - rand.nextInt(5)) + min,p);

    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
        mHandler = new Handler();
        r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "PRE REDRAW ");
                ReDraw();
                Log.v(TAG,"AFTER REDRAW ");
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            }
        };
            Looper.loop();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}
```

Where ReDraw is:

```
    public void ReDraw()
{
    Log.v("MyActivity","INNER START REDRAW ");
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/4,canvas.getHeight()/5,60,p);
    String output = "";
    output = "Current longitude:" + Double.toString(gpsGo.RequestLocationUpdate().getLongitude()) + " latitude: " + Double.toString(gpsGo.RequestLocationUpdate().getLatitude());
    canvas.drawText(output,canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight() - canvas.getHeight()/3,p);
    Log.v("MyActivity","INNER END REDRAW ");
}
```

In the log I see the Logs but I dont get new anything on the screen. I know this is not the best way to handle a new thread but its just to try to find out why it is not working.

Another approach I had tried was to make Thread thread = new Thread() {...} into a new class that extends Thread and then create that class pass the canvas from the main class and try to redraw, but again i see the log but without any new drawings on the canvas.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Drawing and any UI stuff must occur on the main thread.  What you should do is run the GPS updates in a sepeaate thread and then invalidate your surface so that it redraws from the main thread.

Edit: Reading up a bit more (its been a while since I played with the GPS).  You define a LocationListener and you have an "onLocationChanged" function.  This is called when you move.  Its from this function that you will need to invalidate your view.

Comment: So the new thread will just check for the GPS updates and call canvasobject.invalidate() / postinvalidate() ?

Comment: yes view sorry, hmm well i will have to take a look when i get back home but thanks!

Comment: well @Goz the thing GPSGo is a whole different class and I wouldnt want to include more stuff that are not GPS related. like a view.invalidate

What I was thinking in the "listener" of the drawing class was to do a locationManager.getLastKnownLocation() <== custom function that checks between gps,network,passive and if the location provided is <> from the old then redraw

Comment: @drakoumelitos: You could do that but you will end up wasting some battery power.  It shouldn't be too bad but allowing the kernel to wake you up when it needs to will give you best battery performance.